# Are wildcards in java only applicable to collections?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am not able to figure out how to declare a parameter in a function or a field in a class using ? wildcard without using any collection.
For eg. I can write something like List l1 but how do I use ? without using List or any such collection.

Comment: Can you please show your code ? We have no clue what you did in your code.

Comment: The answer to question from your subject is "no". But the rest of your question is not clear to me. Please show your code and explain better your concrete problem.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard generic can be used with any generic type, for example `Class<?>`

```
public void myFunction(Class<?> theObject) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every parameterized class can accept wildcards. Just because collections are the most representative example of generics usage, you are not limited to them.

Usually, you use the ? wildcard when you're not sure about the actual parameter class and you want to avoid raw types.